# How to configure file permissions for written files on my FreeBSD NFS server?

Tags: nfs, freebsd

**TLDR:** When I copy a file from my macOS client to the FreeBSD NFS server, it's written with 777 permission and owned by 501:staff.

In my example below, I want "license.properties" to be owned by myuser:staff and have 664 permissions.

---

**This is the command I used to mount the NFS share on my Mac**

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.1.229:/mnt/storage-mypc ~/test
```

**FreeBSD setup:**

```
mypc% pwd
/mnt/storage-mypc/my-stuff

mypc% ls -al
total 140
drwsrwsr-x  10 myuser  staff   11 Nov 22 23:44 apps

mypc% ls -al apps 
total 66
-rwxrwxrwx   1 501    staff  232 Nov 10 15:06 license.properties

mypc% cat /etc/exports 
/mnt/storage-mypc -maproot=myuser -network 192.168.1/24
/mnt/storage-mypc -maproot=myuser -network 192.168.2/24

mypc% showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:
/mnt/storage-mypc                 192.168.1.0 192.168.2.0 

mypc% cat /etc/rc.conf
clear_tmp_enable="YES"
syslogd_flags="-ss"
sendmail_enable="NONE"
hostname="mypc"
wlans_iwm0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
sshd_enable="YES"
ntpd_enable="YES"
powerd_enable="YES"
# Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
dumpdev="NO"
zfs_enable="YES"

######################################
#mypc

mountd_enable="YES"
nfs_server_enable="YES"
rpcbind_enable="YES"

ifconfig_re0="inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most OS ignore the setuid bit on directories (BSD included).

You either need to have the same names on both client and server or downgrade to NFSv3 and setup idmap.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by "same names"? Thanks

Comment: Note: On Unix/BSD, they are "directories" and not the user/Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.